# MySQL Conversion to DATE Type

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

What is the difference between the return values for these two expressions in MySQL:

`date('2011-01-01')`

`cast('2011-01-01' AS DATE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two, you get a date field in both instances